# If a current flows through a wire connecting two poles of a battery, how high an external voltage must I apply to stop the current flowing?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, voltage

Imagine two poles of a battery to be one meter separated from each other. We connect the poles with a conducting wire after which a current flows. Can we stop the current from flowing by placing the battery between two large charged parallel plates? If so, how high must the voltage between the plates be compared to the voltage of the battery?
I know that a static electric field can't penetrate a metal. But what will be the case if a current flows through it?

Comment: Accept the correct answer. The pictures were pretty, but the analysis was flawed.

Comment: @Deschele Schilder I have updated my answer. I am not saying that this answer is 100% correct and I assume ideal case. However after further investigation things seem more complicated and unless an analytical solution to the problem is given I regard this question a big question mark!

Comment: This situation can be modeled using [Bruce Sherwood's circuit/wire/field simulation](https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/matterandinteractions/folder/matterandinteractions/program/18-SurfaceCharge).  I think the program would need modification to include an external object (the capacitor) but I don't think that would be too difficult.

Comment: @Deschele Schilder Try to tag the question with "physics" and "electromagnetism" as well.

Comment: @Deschele Schilder I believe the answers here accepted as being the most valid are under serious dispute. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437511/effect-of-an-external-electric-field-on-a-electric-current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we stop the current from flowing by placing the battery between two large charged parallel plates?

No.

[I am assuming that the wire is not in electrical contact with the plates. Perhaps there are holes in the plates for the wires to pass through, or alternatively, the wire enters the cavity between the plates from the sides, then turns perpendicular to the plates, and then again, exits through the side. One final arrangement is that the entire circuit is in the cavity between the plates. The result is the same for all three configurations as long as the wire is not in electrical contact with the plates.]

As the voltage across the plates is increased, the wire will develop charges at the points of nearest approach to the plates. [That is, the electrons in the wire, will re-arrange themselves]. These charges will be opposite to the charges in the plate. They will create a $\vec{E}$ field in the wire equal and opposite to that created by the plates in the wire. The net effect will be that the emf applied by the battery will drive the same current through the wire with or without charges on the plates.

[On a side note, the electric field between two plates with nothing but a dielectric between them appears as parallel lines (with some fringing at the sides) as drawn in the original question. However, the electric field between two plates with a wire between them, even though not electrically connected, will be substantially different, whether or not there is current flowing through the wire.]

Comment: This seems in contradiction with the first answer, but I can't see why. What if the entire battery-wire system is placed between the plates, so without holes?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder It _is_ in contradiction to the first answer. The first answer is incorrect. If there are no holes, then the plates of the capacitor are in electrical contact with the wires, at least according to the diagram in the first answer. Then you have a system with two power supplies (one for the wire, one for the plates), and two resistors (the wire between the plates, and the wire outside of the plates). Kirchhoff's laws will determine the net current.

Comment: I haven't drawn a diagram. I only described the situation. The wire is only in contact with the two terminals of the battery. Without being in contact with the plates (Imagine a small 9V battery with a wire between the poles; this system we put between the plates, without touching the plates)

Comment: "this system we put between the plates, without touching the plates" The result will be the same, whether you place the entire circuit between the plates, put part of the circuit between the plates, or have holes in the plates through which the wire passes. The electrons in the wire will re-arrange themselves "opposite" to the charges in the plates.

Comment: I know that a static electric field can't penetrate a metal. So this is also the case if the metal carries an electric current?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder sort of. The static field does affect the wire. It creates a balancing static field within the wire. Then the principle of superposition says that the final field will be the sum of the original static field, the balancing field induced in the wire by the original field, and the field induced by the battery.

Comment: The first answer is incorrect. This answer is correct.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Of course an electric static field on air can induce a current on a conductor line aligned to the field. Otherelse we would not have antennas! What are you talking about!! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212647/can-an-electric-field-help-generate-a-current#:~:text=Yes.,other%20end%20to%20the%20cloth.

Comment: @Markoul11 Where did I say it can't?

Comment: "I know that a static electric field can't penetrate a metal"...?

Comment: @Markoul11 Ah, yes. Initially yes. But if the situation is steady, there is no electric field inside the conductor.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy You answer would be correct if the wire (red in figure provided) was not powered by a second voltage source. There is no back emf on the wire since it is connected to a second voltage source. When the two steady powered fields on the possition of the conductor line cancel out, there cannot be any electric current present on this wire segment.

Comment: There is no difference between a field mediated by a medal  medium with that mediarted by air. Both are mediums of electricity. If you create a strong enough field between the plates of the capacitor to cancel out the emf on the wire the flow of current will stop. Of course air is a bad conductor Mvolts on the plates would be propably needed to cancel even a few mA small current on the wire.

Comment: @Markoul11 "There is no difference between a field mediated by a medal medium with that mediarted by air." That is incorrect. If conductive material replaces dielectric material in an electric field, it will _change_ the shape and strength of the field, because charges in the conductor will re-arrange themselves, and if the electric field was generated by charged conductive plates, the charges in those plates will re-arrange themselves as well. Conductors in an electric field do not act the same as dielectrics.

Comment: My answer to this point was qualitative not quantitative. All materials can be characterized in some degree as being insulators (i.e. dielectric) or contuctors. Even a conductor has dielectric coefficient and a dielectric a conductivity parameter. Air can be made conductive if enough voltage is applied to the plates. So what will happen then if the two opposite and equal currents meet in our red conductor line (see figure)? Cancellation.

Comment: Air is conductive when it ionized. If you have sufficient voltage to ionize the air, then the assumption that the wire and the plates are not electrically connected is violated. Further, the plates will now be discharging. The discharging of the plates due to current through ionized air is the only way there would be a counter-current to that induced by the battery.

Comment: You can have electric current on air without forming and short-circuit arc. It is called dielectric leakage.  what if the wire now is pvc insulated? What then? Only an experiment can tell. Anyway, let's agree that we disagree. Thanks for your input.

Comment: This situation can be modeled using [Bruce Sherwood's circuit/wire/field simulation](https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/matterandinteractions/folder/matterandinteractions/program/18-SurfaceCharge).  I think the program would need modification to include an external object (the capacitor) but I don't think that would be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming a straight electrical wire with no dielectric insulation (i.e. dielectric constant of wire insulation would reduce the *displacement* *Ec* *field* of the capacitor), positioned perpendicular to the plates of the capacitor as shown in the figure and provided, also that the wire is powered by a different source than the capacitor and the capacitor is fully charged, then the short answer is ideally,

when ***Ec(inside wire)=-Ew***                 (Eq.1)

where  *Ec(inside wire)≠Ec* (i.e. Ec value in vacuum)

The two electric fields *Ec(inside wire)* of the capacitor and *Ew* of the voltage source *Vw* inside the wire will cancel out and no electric current *Iw* will flow through the wire.

Practically, this means that you must make sure that the polarity (+/-) of the source powering the wire is opposite to the polarity of the voltage source *V* powering the two plates of the capacitor and quantitatively that the *displacement current* between the capacitor plates is made equal and opposite sign of the d.c. current *Iw* flowing through the wire thus,

***Ic(maximum peak)******=-Iw*** (Eq.2)

The *displacement current* between the plates of a fully charged capacitor (i.e. when fully charged, current on the capacitor circuit lines is ideally zero *Ic=0*) is the **maximum peak** value measured of *Ic* current at the beginning of the capacitor charging period.

Meaning that you have to choose the correct value of source voltage *V* for your capacitor circuit that would cancel out the current on the wire *Iw*.

You could do a theoretical calculation but it would be complicated with a possible large error bar, knowing the exact resistivity and impedance values of the two circuits but if your question is related to a practical application and assuming your capacitor in the circuit is fast charging, you could just keep increasing *V* voltage value until you measure *Iw=0.*

**Updated figure added 14 May 2021:** Because it seems that there is a lot of confusion created about the previous figure also seen in this answer, I have added a second version of the circuit schematic that I hope will clarify things. The conventional flow of current is used.
[image: updatd version of figure]

**Answer update added 22 May 2021:** The electric field *Ew* inside a current carrying wire connected to a voltage source is not zero. The *E=0* case inside a conductor holds only for Electrostatics and not for a current carrying conductor where the electric field inside the conductor is not zero, *E≠0*. The whole point of this circuit is that the naked wire (marked as red) inside the field of the capacitor is connected to a voltage source therefore electrostatic equilibrium is continuously disturbed and never reached. physics.stackexchange.com/a/250651/183646 There is definitely *Ew* present opposite to *Ec* all the time after the capacitor is charged. We can assume the **capacitor is in vacuum** to avoid dielectric leakage and therefore an ideal case. The fields will interact and therefore affect the current on the wire. Of course because the huge difference of conductivity between the air and the wire a huge voltage Vc would be needed on the plates of the capacitor to zero even a small current on the wire Iw.

The system operation is not linear. Putting *Vw* at 0 results to electrostatic equilibrium and surface charge on the wire with the electric field inside the wire *Ew=0*. However, putting *Vw* to any non-zero value gives *Ew≠0* inside the wire. Therefore you cannot superposition for *Vw=0*. Things are more complicated,
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018874523513 , [https://www.if.ufrj.br/~dore/Fis3/Assis_et_al.pdf](https://www.if.ufrj.br/%7Edore/Fis3/Assis_et_al.pdf) .

I am not saying that my answer is 100% correct and it is assuming ideal case. However after further investigation things seem more complicated and unless an exact analytical solution to the problem is given or a related experiment is presented I regard this question a big question mark!

**Answer update 28 May 2021:** https://tinyurl.com/2ca5byv7 There is a experiment done by Oleg Jefimenko showing clearly the axial homogeneous electric field formed inside an d.c.  electric current carrying wire.  The question now is will the electric homogeneous vectors inside the wire of this field interact with the electrostatic aligned field of the capacitor?

**Final answer update 29 May 2021:**

Except the case of Vw=0 where there is electrostatic Equilibrium and Ew=0 inside the wire and therefore the operation of our system is not linear compared with all other values of Vw≠0 where there is an electric field created inside the wire due the current Ew≠0 by the Vw voltage source and there is no electrostatic equilibrium formed on the wire that can repel an external electrostatic field and thus the case Vm=0 cannot be used in the analysis, then,

"*Electric fields are fully described by Maxwells eqs, which are linear in both E and B. Linearity implies superposition, which means that the fields do not interact with each other, but simply add vectorially. If they have equal and opposite amplitudes at any point, the resultant will be zero - i.e.exact cancellation at that point. That is true for both static and time/spatially varying fields.*" [https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/411049/183646]

Therefore my initial answer **is correct** .

Comment: There are a number of errors in your answer. I will only point out one in this comment. There is no displacement current in a capacitor except when it is charging or discharging. "The displacement current between the plates of a fully charged capacitor (i.e. when fully charged, current on the capacitor circuit lines is ideally zero Ic=0) is the maximum peak value measured of Ic current at the beginning of the capacitor charging period." No, the displacement current through the dielectric of a capacitor is always equal to the conduction current through the leads of that capacitor.

Comment: This answer is incorrect

Comment: Keep in mind that the red wire in the figure is powered by a second D.C. voltage source.

Comment: Displacement current is a concept invented by Maxwell to describe how an electric field is propagated across the parallel plates of a capacitor. During the charging period of the capacitor the displacement current across the plates of the capacitor equals always the conduction current on the lines of the capacitor's circuit.

Comment: However, there is an interesting argument, what happens after the capacitor ideally is fully charged? How is then the electric field propagated across the capacitor's plates? To go around this caveat we theoretically assume that the displacement current between the parallel plates of the capacitor is always present even after the capacitor is charged and responsible for the electric field between its plates. The value of the displacement current after the capacitor is charged ideally then we say equals the maximum value of the the conduction current during charge.

Comment: @Markoul11 "During the charging period of the capacitor the displacement current across the plates of the capacitor equals always the conduction current on the lines of the capacitor's circuit. " Always, not just "during the charging period".  "we theoretically assume that the displacement current between the parallel plates of the capacitor is always present even after the capacitor is charged" No, this is wrong. Diplacement current requires a _changing_ voltage. "and responsible for the electric field between its plates" no it is not.

Comment: @Markoul11 "The value of the displacement current after the capacitor is charged ideally then we say equals the maximum value of the the conduction current during charge" That is just plain wrong. If the capacitor is not charging or discharging, there is NO displacement current. If you were taught otherwise, you were misinformed.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I have updated my answer. I am not saying that this answer is correct. However after further investigation things seem more complicated and unless an analytical solution to the problem is given I regard this question a big question mark!

Comment: The question is indeed: will a constant electric field still be unable to enter a metal if the metal is carrying a current. I'm not so sure anymore it can't!

Comment: Yes indeed this is ontologically the deepest question. The problem is I can't find a related experiment report. I think I have to do it myself.

Comment: @Deschele Schilder unfortunately you are being duped by a person who is confidently wrong. Maxwell’s equations are linear and Ohm’s law is linear. That is all that we have in this scenario. Therefore the situation is linear and superposition applies.

Comment: @Markoul11 it is clear that you do not understand either linearity or superposition. If you claim non-linearity then please write down exactly which law is nonlinear. Maxwell’s equations and Ohm’s law are linear, so what other law do you believe governs this system.

Comment: @Dale I've already replied. See last comment at the bottom of the page.

Comment: And in your reply you have not addressed the substantive issue of linearity. Maxwell’s equations and Ohm’s law are linear. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder https://socratic.org/questions/how-does-an-electric-field-affect-the-movement-of-a-charge . I don't see any reason why they two electric fields Ew and Ec will not interact depending also the strength of the Ec field. Especially, since in a hot wire there s no electrostatic charge build up on the surface of the wire to repel an external electric field. All free charges are going with the current inside the wire.

Comment: @Markoul11 said “I don't see any reason why they two electric fields Ew and Ec will not interact depending also the strength of the Ec field” the reason is linearity. What you describe is non-linear behavior. You also said “in a hot wire there s no electrostatic charge build up on the surface of the wire” which is completely false. Surface charges are essential for the functioning of active circuits. This is discussed by Jackson and many many other authors.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/2ca5byv7 There is an experiment done by Oleg Jefimenko showing clearly the axial homogeneous electric field formed inside a d.c.  electric current carrying wire.  The question now is will the electric homogeneous vectors inside the wire of this field interact with the electrostatic aligned field of the capacitor?

Comment: @Markoul11 said “The question now is will the electric homogeneous vectors inside the wire of this field interact with the electrostatic aligned field of the capacitor?” Linearity provides a very easy way to answer that question. Interestingly, the quote you added in your answer completely opposes both your answer and your claim that it is nonlinear, despite your subsequent claim that therefore your initial answer is correct. I note that you have also failed to produce an actual non-linear equation describing the situation

Comment: @Markoul11 said “Except the case of Vw=0 where there is electrostatic Equilibrium and Ew=0 inside the wire and therefore the operation of our system is not linear” This is complete rubbish. There is nothing in Maxwell’s equations that supports this claim. Nowhere does Maxwell’s equations become non-linear for non-zero values of any variable in the equations.

Comment: @Dale Please refrain form using inflammatory comments. Neither says Maxwell that you can use his equations in a binary behavior system the way you used them in your analysis. The system goes from having pure electrostatic behavior Ew=0  for Vw=0 to no electrostatic Ew≠0 for Vw≠0 inside the wire. A whole new field Ew with non zero values is added to the system! You cannot use Vw=0 case for analyzing your system because Vw=0 does not mean that the Vm source circuit loop is open.  I will not respond to any other replies from you. Let us agree that we disagree.

Comment: @Markoul11 I do apologize, I should not use inflammatory language. I am just frustrated because you are not merely wrong but you are obviously wrong. I do not understand how you can not see it. Maxwell’s equations are linear (you have yet to produce a non-linear equation). Linearity means you can use the principle of superposition. That means you can find the effect of two sources together simply by finding the effect of each source alone and adding them. Your new quote confirms that. When you add the two sources together you get current. You “agree to disagree” with Maxwell and linearity

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Markoul11 is incorrect and the answer by @Math Keeps Me Busy is correct. The easiest way to analyze this problem is to use the principle of superposition as follows:

Both Maxwell’s equations and the equations of circuit theory are linear. This means that you can find the total current through the wire by simply finding the current due to each source individually and summing them.

To get rid of a voltage source we simply give it a voltage of 0. And in all cases we are considering the voltage source (a battery) to be operating at DC steady state.

Setting the external voltage source to 0 and the connected source to $V_{\text{connected}}$ can be analyzed with the usual circuit theory, and gives the standard Ohm’s law current. So in this case there is a current in the wire and a linearly changing voltage inside the wire, and a surface charge which produces the correct field distribution inside the wire. https://doi.org/10.1119/1.18112

Setting the connected source to zero and the external source to $V_{\text{external}}$ cannot be analyzed with circuit theory, but is easy to analyze with Maxwell’s equations. The $V_\text{connected}=0$ "short circuits" that connection, giving a closed conductive loop. Since it is DC steady state this is a simple conductor in an external electrostatic field. A surface charge is induced on the loop and the current is zero. Importantly, the surface charge opposes the external field so that there is no field inside the conductor. So in this case there is no current inside the wire and no voltage inside the wire, just an external surface charge canceling out the external field.

Once we have analyzed each source independently we can simply add the two results together to determine the current from both sources together. So when both $V_{\text{external}}$ and $V_{\text{connected}}$ are on we have the non-zero current from the connected source added to the zero current from the external source to produce a non-zero current. We also have the non-zero internal voltage gradient from the connected source added to the zero internal voltage from the external source to produce a non-zero internal voltage gradient. Finally, we have the non-zero surface charge distribution from the connected source and also the non-zero surface charges from the external source added to produce a non-zero total surface charge distribution. In summary, the external source produces 0 current and cannot stop the current from the connected source. Its effect is solely to alter the usual surface charge distribution on the wire.

Comment: Wouldn't the external field cancel the "inner voltage" of the battery?

Comment: @Deschele Schilder no, the only effect of the external field is to induce a surface charge on the wire. That is the whole point of using the principle of superposition.

Comment: I disagree. The whole point of this circuit is that the naked wire (marked as red) inside the field of the capacitor is connected to a voltage source therefore electrostatic equilibrium is continuously disturbed and never reached. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/250651/183646 There is definitely Ew present opposite to Ec all the time after the capacitor is charged. We can assume the capacitor is in vacuum to avoid leakage. The fields will interact and therefore affect the current on the wire.

Comment: @Markoul11 your argument is incorrect. Maxwell’s equations are linear, and your argument is only valid for a non-linear system. Please read up on the principle of superposition before posting any more EM answers. The fields don’t interact other than to simply add. We know the effect of each source individually, the total effect is just the sum. Your vague idea of “electrostatic equilibrium is continuously disturbed” is made precise with superposition.

Comment: @Dale But the system operation is not linear! Putting Vw at 0 results to electrostatic equilibrium and surface charge on the wire with the electric field inside the wire Ew=0. However, putting Vw to any non-zero value gives Ew≠0 inside the wire. Therefore you cannot superposition for Vw=0. Things are more complicated, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018874523513 , pdf: https://www.if.ufrj.br/~dore/Fis3/Assis_et_al.pdf

Comment: This situation can be modeled using [Bruce Sherwood's circuit/wire/field simulation](https://www.glowscript.org/#/user/matterandinteractions/folder/matterandinteractions/program/18-SurfaceCharge).  I think the program would need modification to include an external object (the capacitor) but I don't think that would be too difficult.

Comment: @Markoul11 what is the exact nonlinearity here? Be specific and write down the non-linear equation describing the source of this supposed non-linearity. Maxwell’s equations are linear and Ohm’s law is linear, so I don’t see any room for non linearity.

Comment: You used in your analysis electrostatic equilibrium claiming because of that that the the Ec field does not penetrate  the wire since there is no field inside the wire Ew=0. But this is no true in our case we examine of an electric current carrying wire where Ew≠0 and there is an electric field Ew inside the wire antiparallel aligned to Ec. A "hot" electric wire has no electrostatic charge on its surface never reaches electrostatic equilibrium and therefore will not repel the field of the capacitor Ec. The question here is IMO, will Ec field of the capacitor penetrate an electric hot wire?

Comment: @Markoul11 you clearly do not understand how linearity or superposition works and you have not shown any indication that the system is nonlinear. The fact that the wire is carrying current and has an E field inside is accounted for in my analysis.  Also, it is 100% unambiguously false that “A "hot" electric wire has no electrostatic charge on its surface”.

Comment: Regarding the surface charge on a current carrying wire, see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256681/surface-charge-on-a-resistive-wire-in-dc-circuit https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516656/why-is-there-an-electric-potential-drop-across-the-resistor/516745?noredirect=1#comment1433058_516745 many other similar posts here and discussions in Jackson’s text

Comment: @Dale An electric d.c. current carrying wire CANNOT build up any electrostatic charge on its surface. Current means motion of negatively charged particles i.e. electrons towards the end which is more positively charged than the other end. So for carrying current there are no loss of any charged particles, they are just moving one way so overall charge of the wire is zero i.e. the wire is static neutral. While the electrons move through the wire, the number of positive charges is equal to the number of negative charges formed due to motion. Therefore a wire carrying currents is static neutral.

Comment: @dale "you clearly do not understand how linearity or superposition works". You treat Vw=0 case in your analysis as an open loop circuit which does not apply in our present circuit which is for Vw=0 still a closed loop circuit, Your analysis is flawed. Whatever the ALWAYS closed source Vm circuit concerns in our example given in the figure, by superposition when Ec(inside wire)=-Ew, i.e. Ec(inside wire)≠Ec(vacuum), they will vectorial add cancel out and current in the wire will be zero Iw=0.

Comment: @Markoul11 said "An electric d.c. current carrying wire CANNOT build up any electrostatic charge on its surface". This is completely false. Not only can they build up a surface charge, that charge build up is necessary for them to function. See: (most authoritative) https://doi.org/10.1119/1.18112 (my personal favorite) https://doi.org/10.1119/1.5095939 (other similar references) https://doi.org/10.1119/1.5095939 https://doi.org/10.1119/1.3456567 (video demonstration of surface charge on DC circuit) https://youtu.be/U7RLg-691eQ There are many more similar references. This is a well-known fact

Comment: @Markoul11 said "You treat Vw=0 case in your analysis as an open loop circuit which does not apply in our present circuit which is for Vw=0 still a closed loop circuit" Setting the connected source to zero gives a short circuit, not an open circuit. So I agree that it is a closed loop circuit. That is well understood, but perhaps poorly communicated since this is one of the few points that we agree on. I have updated my answer accordingly to communicate more clearly on this point

Comment: @Dale I have upvoted two of your last comments as useful contribution to the discussion. I am confident  that we can resolve this dispute which I believe is a semantics disagreement on how the Maxwell eqs can be applied on this circuit. Of course I do not refute any of the Maxwell equations and they linear nature.

Comment: @Markoul11 I appreciate that. However, this is a substantive disagreement, not a semantic disagreement. You predict that the current is zero and I predict that it is non-zero. This is a substantive disagreement about a measurable outcome of a physical experiment. If you do agree that Maxwell’s equations are linear then the answer is easy to determine and it is not what you claim